# MySql set variable using Select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a stored procedure as

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GetInfo(
    in userid varchar (150),
    out fname varchar (50),     
    out lname varchar (50),     
    out user_status varchar (30),
    out reg_date DATETIME
)
BEGIN
    select fname=users_table.first_name,
            lname=users_table.last_name,
            user_status=users_table.user_status,
            reg_date=users_table.reg_date
    FROM users_table
    WHERE users_table.userid=userid;
END$$
```

I am using it like

```
SET @fname=@lname=@user_status=@reg_date=NULL;
CALL GetInfo(
    'XYZ',
    @fname,
    @lname,
    @user_status,
    @reg_date
);

SELECT @fname,@lname,@user_status,@reg_date;
```

But I am getting only NULL values. I think that problem is with variable assignment using Select statement.

I know that in MSSQLSERVER, we can assign variable in SELECT statement as I have but I am not sure about MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change the SQL in you procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GetInfo(
    in userid varchar (150),
    out fname varchar (50),     
    out lname varchar (50),     
    out p_user_status varchar (30),
    out p_reg_date DATETIME
)
BEGIN
    select users_table.first_name,
            users_table.last_name,
            users_table.user_status,
            users_table.reg_date

    into fname,lname,p_user_status,p_reg_date   
    FROM users_table
    WHERE users_table.userid=userid

    limit 1;
END$$
```

Variable names must be different than fields

And will work